# How can I easily create a strongly typed object from an anonymous object in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, strong-typing, anonymous-objects

I have some JSON containing anonymous objects coming to my client-side. Is there some built-in mechanism or external library for converting these anonymous objects into strongly-typed TypeScript objects? Is there something like AutoMapper for doing this?

My objects are complex types, with complex types as properties.

Comment: You need to write the mapper yourself (or download code from the net) -- for example, most libraries will have a ``mixin`` function that allows you to mixin properties from one object to another.  Then just cast your strongly-typed object into ``any`` and pass it into the mapper with your JSON object.  The strongly-typed object will be filled just like any plain old JavaScript object.

Answer (score 9):

Get some sample data and place it in a .ts file:

```
var people = [
    {
        "name": "bob", "height": 150, "pets": [{ "name": "spot", "species": "dog" }]
    },
    {
        "name": "jane", "height": 142, "pets": [{ "name": "lucy", "species": "cat" }]
    }
];
```

Run `tsc --declaration yourFile.ts`

Now you'll have `yourFile.d.ts`:

```
declare var people: {
    "name": string;
    "height": number;
    "pets": {
        "name": string;
        "species": string;
    }[];
}[];
```

Replace `declare var people:` with `interface Person`, remove the trailing `[]`, and (optionally) remove the quotes:

```
interface Person {
    name: string;
    height: number;
    pets: {
        name: string;
        species: string;
    }[];
}
```

Comment: This is nice, but I was looking for something that could do it for me on the fly.

Comment: @RyanShripat when you say "on the fly" do you mean automatically generate the file, or do it at runtime?

Comment: I want to be able to say: var people = [...] /* anonymous JSON object */; then say: People p = ConvertAnonToStrong(people);, with errors at run-time if the conversion doesn't work.

Comment: "with errors at run-time if the conversion doesn't work" - TypeScript is a compile time only language that produces pure JavaScript, so it can't provide runtime type constraints.

Answer (score 3):

Recently I created an AutoMapper implementation in TypeScript / JavaScript exactly for this scenario. I have put the code at GitHub ([AutoMapperTS](http://b.ldmn.nl/AutoMapperTS)). You can also use the library directly using the [automapper-ts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/automapper-ts) NPM package or [automapper-ts](http://bower.io/search/?q=automapper-ts) Bower package.

The library is almost fully documented. Furthermore, quite a lot of Jasmine unit tests are already available (code coverage is over 90%). They should provide you with some explanation of needed.

I hope this library suits your needs. Should you have any questions and/or remarks, please don't hesitate contacting me!

Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for an easy way to convert json data from a web service to an interface too. Didn't found what I need but here is my solution. Noticed that I added a "Pet" interface and added another pet to your json. Also had to specify the anonymous object as "any". You can cut/paste this to TypeScript playground (http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html) to see the results. Hope this helps.

```
let header = document.createElement("div");
header.textContent = "Test";
document.body.appendChild(header);

var people:any = [
    {
        "name": "bob", "height": 150, "pets": [{ "name": "spot", "species": "dog" }, {"name" : "violet", "species": "shark"}]
    },
    {
        "name": "jane", "height": 142, "pets": [{ "name": "lucy", "species": "cat" }]
    }
];

interface Pet {
    name: string;
    species: string;
}
interface Person {
    name: string;
    height: number;
    pets: Array<Pet>
}

class Foo {
    convertToObject = (person: Person) => person;
}


var person = new Foo().convertToObject(people[0]);

let div = document.createElement("div");
div.textContent = `hey ${person.name} I see you have ${person.pets.length} pet`;
document.body.appendChild(div);
```